# How to fix Web Api 2 issue on live server

Tags: jquery, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on MVC 5 web application, Recently I have deployed this application to the server. The problem is, the Api is not working on the live server, however the same Api is working perfectly when I run this on localhost.

It gives me the following error:

```
jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4 DELETE http://mywebsite.com/api/test/2 405 (Method Not Allowed)
```

Comment: I do not think we have enough information to help troubleshooting.  Please include a [mcve] to the question - for example, what is your jquery method invoking (are you sure you have a URL mapping on your app for the`DELETE` method?) - double check the entire URL

Comment: I am using ajax to invoke this method. and yes the URL is correct because its working on the localhost.

Comment: Can you also make sure you have the correct version deployed on the server then?

Comment: Yes, I checked. that was correct. I solved the issue and mentioned in the answer. 
Thanks for your help  :)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by modifying the Web.Config File.

```
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"> <-- added attribute
      <remove name="WebDAVModule"/> <-- added this line
```

Answer (score 0):

Would recommend to use Deligating Handler which will log what ever comes in and goes out of your Web API. This can even log if the method is being called using wrong verb like POST is being called as PUT.

Following is one of the sample log....[image]

There is a very beautifully written post by Dave Donaldson(http://arcware.net/logging-web-api-requests/) which can be used as it is, just add your database or file logging code :)

This will help in future :) :)